# Track clicks in webview Android

Tags: android, android-webview

I have been facing with a serious issue since weeks! I want to track all the clicks done in a Android webview. I know, the solution is implementing WebViewClient, but that doesn't track the clicks done in frames!

Example -

When you open a website within google translate, webviewclient doesn't track clicks made in the translated page!

Secondly, even when using Android 3.0, when i open google.com, it shows Google instant i think, and i am unable to track that url!

I'll be very very thankful if you can help me with this.

Thanks
Nithin

Answer (score 0):

If it is your own Web content, you should track this in JavaScript.

If it is not your own Web content, it's conceivable you could cook up some general-purpose JavaScript for this and apply it via `loadUrl("javascript:...")` and `addJavascriptInterface()`, but I wouldn't know the details, as I'm not a low-level JS+DOM expert.

`WebViewClient` itself does not handle all scenarios, as you note, and it is the only pure Java solution I know of.

Comment: No..it's not my own web content :(